# Can we have a [pollution] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I asked a [question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/30927/what-happens-to-rocket-stages-that-land-in-the-oceans-and-how-many-are-still-th) about jettisoned rocket parts residing in the ocean, and tagged it with [waste](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/waste), but this tag was removed in an edit, presumably because most other instances of this tag relate waste products from humans or spacecraft in space, so it wasn't considered a good fit.

That got me thinking that perhaps a [pollution](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pollution) tag would be useful, and appropriate for my question.

I don't have the rep to create tags, so I'll leave it up to the community to decide.

Comment: Ok, I created the tag and put guidance on both it and the waste tag. I also tagged your question and the four questions I identified in my answer.

Comment: Nice -- thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It does look like there are at least [four questions](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=pollution+-%22light+pollution%22+is%3Aquestion) to which the tag would apply, so I think it would be reasonable to consider a tag for it at this point.

Comment: We should probably put guidance on the waste tag first, and then put guidance on the pollution tag when we create it. That way we can keep them distinct.